# Printing variable after filter objects python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm currently creating a list made up of a filter object that queries variables and ignores the variables that are false and print the resulting list, and a variable on the same line afterwards that is not included in the filter. For example:

```
nature = "cow"
creator = ""
minor = ""
item = "hammer"
NAMEPROPERTIES = [nature, creator, minor]
propertiestrue = (filter(None, NAMEPROPERTIES))
```

Then I try:

```
print (*propertiestrue)
cow
```

Which works, as the output is cow, but:

```
print (*propertiestrue, item)
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

I have also tried separating off the filter section completely:

```
print ((*filter(None, NAMEPROPERTIES)), nature)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
```

I have tried printing the filter directly rather than making a list out of it first with the same results. My problem is, how do I get 'item' to print on the same line as the output of (*propertiestrue)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

nature = "cow"
creator = ""
minor = ""
item = "hammer"
NAMEPROPERTIES = [nature, creator, minor]
propertiestrue = filter(None, NAMEPROPERTIES)

print(*chain(propertiestrue , [item]))
```

---

```
cow hammer
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Thank you! I'll accept when the system allows me to.